# QtPIM fails to compile using qmake

Tags: qt, makefile, qt5, qmake, pim

I am currently trying to compile the [qtpim](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtpim.git/?h=v5.0.0-beta1) library. I did so using the following commands:

**$ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtpim.git**

```
Cloning into 'qtpim'...
remote: Counting objects: 25257, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8419/8419), done.
remote: Total 25257 (delta 19142), reused 21557 (delta 16688)
Receiving objects: 100% (25257/25257), 14.96 MiB | 435.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (19142/19142), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

**$ cd qtpim/**

**$ git checkout v5.0.0-beta1**

```
Note: checking out 'v5.0.0-beta1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at a869b9a... Removed one un-used file.
```

**$ qmake**

```
Info: creating cache file $HOME/git/qtpim/.qmake.cache
```

**$ make**

```
Makefile:619: warning: overriding recipe for target 'docs'
Makefile:610: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'docs'
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt/bin/qmake $HOME/git/qtpim/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '$HOME/git/qtpim/src'
cd contacts/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt/bin/qmake $HOME/git/qtpim/src/contacts/contacts.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile
Project ERROR: Module does not define version.
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'sub-contacts-make_first-ordered' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-contacts-make_first-ordered] Error 3
make[1]: Leaving directory '$HOME/git/qtpim/src'
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Poorly, there is no README or INSTALL file or anything else in the [file tree](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtpim.git/tree/?h=v5.0.0-beta1). What did I miss to get qmake compiling this library?

Comment: Why 5.0.0? It's 5 years old!

Comment: @peppe its the only version tagged in the git repo, and some software I try to use requires the library. By the way the upstream version fails with `Some of the required modules (false) are not available.`

Comment: Then checkout an up-to-date branch (5.6? master? dev?) and use that one. qtpim isn't part of any official Qt release, hence it doesn't get tagged, you're supposed to use the latest branch.